# Question view count shows zero despite having an answer

Tags: support, status-bydesign, views

How is it possible that a question can have zero (0) views and yet also have an answer?

[image: screenshot of question with 0 views, but an answer]

Doesn't having an answer mean that there was at least one view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Views are buffered and cached, so it is normal to see the viewcount lag behind the actual value a bit.

If this persists for an hour or more let us know, but I doubt it will.

Comment: never experienced that before. Usually I can see some view in seconds after posting. This post had 9 views after 42 mins... I'll keep an eye on it...